# is it possible to set to download Android apps only from links on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I am planning distribute the Android application in-house. How do I set to download Android App from only link like the "Unlisted App" on the App Store.  (it does not appear in store rankings or search results.)

we would like to download it via Google Play if possible, but is it possible?

Comment: You can try to publish beta version

Comment: is it mean Closed testing or Internal testing on Google Play Console?

Comment: yes, you can try it

Comment: Use Closed Testing, but you need to have the emails of the group you are going to allow in.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, I found this (play.google.com/apps/testing/com.netflix.mediaclient), is this closed testing? and How can I imitate like this?